# Advice on how to reverse the order of a text file in a specific way using C

Tags: c

I have an interesting hypothetical problem/issue that I was wondering how to solve. Ideally I would like to do this for now using C. The issue is thus:

If I have the following in a text file:

1.50 – 1.62 (2H, overlapping m), 1.77 – 1.89 (2H, overlapping m), 1.97 – 2.07 (2H, overlapping m), 2.10 – 2.18 (9H, overlapping m).

How might this be altered to instead read:

2.10 - 2.18 (9H, overlapping m), 1.97 - 2.07 (2H, overlapping m), 1.77 - 1.89 (2H, overlapping m), 1.50 - 1.62 (2H, overlapping m).

Would I have to store each segment in a char array in a linked list and then reverse the order this way? Accounting for the varying length of each segment could be tricky...

Thanks

Comment: Read the whole file to the `char *` buffer. Then traverse it back to front, looking for `),` fragment. Once found -- print all text from last `),` to the result file. I would start coding with this idea, and maybe in the middle of the process you can see some more subtle an elegant way to do that :)

Comment: Try to code something first, otherwise you're on the wrong site here ... and adding to that, I don't understand what you want to do, instead of just giving an example, you should *explain* :o  [it looks like a sorting problem, but the criteria is mysterious]

Comment: the lack of code says that you have not tried to solve this problem yourself.  We are not here to design your algorithm nor to supply you with the code.  We are here to solve the 'it does not compile' and 'it produces the wrong output or seg faults' kind of problems   I.E. compile time and runtime problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file handing/ manipulation and specifically the function:

### fseek()

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

The `fseek()` function is used to set the **file position indicator** for the stream to a new position. This function accepts three arguments. The first argument is the FILE stream pointer returned by the `fopen()` function. The second argument ‘offset’ tells the amount of bytes to seek. The third argument ‘whence’ tells from where the seek of ‘offset’ number of bytes is to be done. The available values for whence are `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, or `SEEK_END`.  These three values (in order) depict the start of the file, the current position and the end of the file. Upon success, this function returns `0`, otherwise it returns `-1`.

> How to reverse the order of the contents a text file?

So, you can start reading your file backwards instead of saving all its content and then reversing its order.

Comment: this method will have LOTS of seeking on the file on the harddisk.  and seeking is VERY slow compared all other harddisk operations and orders of magnitude slower than reading a line at a time from the file and applying some algorithm to reverse the data groups

Comment: @user3629249 his data is structured and it can be incremented by the size of one element (`1.50 – 1.62 (2H, overlapping m`). I highly doubt that incrementing is slower than reading, storing and reversing-element-algorithm implementation. But again, this is just a one possible solution, optimization and complexity are different subject.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question,  you want to sort some data groups, in reverse order.  then output the resulting data groups to a new file.

My suggestions:

```
1) read the input file, a line at a time, perhaps with fgets() or getline()
2) generate a linked list where each node in the list contains one data group.
3) always insert at the 'head' of the linked list 
4) To output, start at the 'head' and walk through the list, outputting the contents of each node.
5) you could use strstr() to find each occurrence of the end of a data group, then use memcpy to place a copy of the data into the new node to be inserted into the front of the linked list.
```

Comment: suggest using ")," for the search string passed to strstr()